# Go JS Tree Mapping view in React TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, gojs

I want to achieve [Tree Mapping](https://gojs.net/beta/samples/treeMapper.html) from Gojs in React typescript.
I found [one](https://codesandbox.io/s/gojs-react-minimal-hooks-forked-6430zt?file=/src/App.js) example of Go js in react but it's still confusing for me to make Tree Mapping in react. Any help would be appreciated to start with Tree Mapping in React TS.
Here is my repo: https://github.com/AdarshPawar29/map-tree-gojs
I manage to create the tree mapping but still some work to be done. I commented on some of the not working functions. I'm also looking for the functional component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import * as go from "gojs";
import { ReactDiagram } from "gojs-react";
import "./App.css";

class TreeNode extends go.Node {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.treeExpandedChanged = (node) => {
      if (node.containingGroup !== null) {
        node.containingGroup
          .findExternalLinksConnected()
          .each((l) => l.invalidateRoute());
      }
    };
  }

  // findVisibleNode() {
  //   // redirect links to lowest visible "ancestor" in the tree
  //   var n = this;
  //   while (n !== null && !n.isVisible()) {
  //     n = n.findTreeParentNode();
  //   }
  //   return n;
  // }
}
// end TreeNode

// Control how Mapping links are routed:
// - "Normal": normal routing with fixed fromEndSegmentLength & toEndSegmentLength
// - "ToGroup": so that the link routes stop at the edge of the group,
//     rather than going all the way to the connected nodes
// - "ToNode": so that they go all the way to the connected nodes
//     but only bend at the edge of the group
var ROUTINGSTYLE = "Normal";

// If you want the regular routing where the Link.[from/to]EndSegmentLength controls
// the length of the horizontal segment adjacent to the port, don't use this class.
// Replace MappingLink with a go.Link in the "Mapping" link template.
class MappingLink extends go.Link {
  getLinkPoint(
    node: go.Node | null | any,
    port: go.GraphObject,
    spot: go.Spot,
    from: boolean,
    ortho: boolean,
    othernode: go.Node | null | any,
    otherport: go.GraphObject
  ) {
    if (ROUTINGSTYLE !== "ToGroup") {
      return super.getLinkPoint(
        node,
        port,
        spot,
        from,
        ortho,
        othernode,
        otherport
      );
    } else {
      var r = port.getDocumentBounds();
      var group = node.containingGroup;
      var b = group !== null ? group.actualBounds : node.actualBounds;
      var op = othernode.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.Center);
      var x = op.x > r.centerX ? b.right : b.left;
      return new go.Point(x, r.centerY);
    }
  }

  computePoints() {
    var result = super.computePoints();
    if (result && ROUTINGSTYLE === "ToNode") {
      var fn = this.fromNode;
      var tn = this.toNode;
      if (fn && tn) {
        var fg = fn.containingGroup;
        var fb = fg ? fg.actualBounds : fn.actualBounds;
        var fpt = this.getPoint(0);
        var tg = tn.containingGroup;
        var tb = tg ? tg.actualBounds : tn.actualBounds;
        var tpt = this.getPoint(this.pointsCount - 1);
        this.setPoint(
          1,
          new go.Point(fpt.x < tpt.x ? fb.right : fb.left, fpt.y)
        );
        this.setPoint(
          this.pointsCount - 2,
          new go.Point(fpt.x < tpt.x ? tb.left : tb.right, tpt.y)
        );
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
// end MappingLink

// Create some random trees in each group
var nodeDataArray = [
  { isGroup: true, key: -1, text: "Left Side", xy: "0 0", width: 150 },
  { isGroup: true, key: -2, text: "Right Side", xy: "300 0", width: 150 },
];
var linkDataArray = [
  { from: 6, to: 1012, category: "Mapping" },
  { from: 4, to: 1006, category: "Mapping" },
  { from: 9, to: 1004, category: "Mapping" },
  { from: 1, to: 1009, category: "Mapping" },
  { from: 14, to: 1010, category: "Mapping" },
];

export default function App() {
  // All links must go from a node inside the "Left Side" Group to a node inside the "Right Side" Group.
  function checkLink(
    fn: {
      [x: string]: any;
      containingGroup: { data: { key: number } } | null;
    },
    fp: any,
    tn: {
      [x: string]: any;
      containingGroup: { data: { key: number } } | null;
    },
    tp: any,
    link: any
  ) {
    // make sure the nodes are inside different Groups
    if (fn.containingGroup === null || fn.containingGroup.data.key !== -1)
      return false;
    if (tn.containingGroup === null || tn.containingGroup.data.key !== -2)
      return false;
    //// optional limit to a single mapping link per node
    if (
      fn.linksConnected.any(
        (l: { category: string }) => l.category === "Mapping"
      )
    )
      return false;
    if (
      tn.linksConnected.any(
        (l: { category: string }) => l.category === "Mapping"
      )
    )
      return false;
    return true;
  }
  function initDiagram() {
    const $ = go.GraphObject.make;
    // set your license key here before creating the diagram: go.Diagram.licenseKey = "...";
    const diagram = $(go.Diagram, {
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true, // must be set to allow for model change listening
      "undoManager.maxHistoryLength": 0, // uncomment disable undo/redo functionality
      "clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData": {
        text: "new node",
        color: "lightblue",
      },
      "commandHandler.copiesTree": true,
      "commandHandler.deletesTree": true,
      // newly drawn links always map a node in one tree to a node in another tree
      "linkingTool.archetypeLinkData": { category: "Mapping" },
      "linkingTool.linkValidation": checkLink,
      "relinkingTool.linkValidation": checkLink,
      model: new go.GraphLinksModel({
        linkKeyProperty: "key", // IMPORTANT! must be defined for merges and data sync when using GraphLinksModel
      }),
    });

    // // define a simple Node template
    // diagram.nodeTemplate = $(
    //   go.Node,
    //   "Auto", // the Shape will go around the TextBlock
    //   new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(
    //     go.Point.stringify
    //   ),
    //   $(
    //     go.Shape,
    //     "RoundedRectangle",
    //     { name: "SHAPE", fill: "white", strokeWidth: 0 },
    //     // Shape.fill is bound to Node.data.color
    //     new go.Binding("fill", "color")
    //   ),
    //   $(
    //     go.TextBlock,
    //     { margin: 8, editable: true }, // some room around the text
    //     new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay()
    //   )
    // );
    diagram.nodeTemplate = $(
      TreeNode,
      { movable: false, copyable: false, deletable: false }, // user cannot move an individual node
      // no Adornment: instead change panel background color by binding to Node.isSelected
      {
        selectionAdorned: false,
        background: "white",
        mouseEnter: (e, node) => (node.background = "aquamarine"),
        // mouseLeave: (e, node) =>
        //   (node.background = node.isSelected ? "skyblue" : "white"),
      },
      new go.Binding("background", "isSelected", (s) =>
        s ? "skyblue" : "white"
      ).ofObject(),
      // whether the user can start drawing a link from or to this node depends on which group it's in
      new go.Binding("fromLinkable", "group", (k) => k === -1),
      new go.Binding("toLinkable", "group", (k) => k === -2),
      $(
        "TreeExpanderButton", // support expanding/collapsing subtrees
        {
          width: 14,
          height: 14,
          "ButtonIcon.stroke": "white",
          "ButtonIcon.strokeWidth": 2,
          "ButtonBorder.fill": "goldenrod",
          "ButtonBorder.stroke": null,
          "ButtonBorder.figure": "Rectangle",
          _buttonFillOver: "darkgoldenrod",
          _buttonStrokeOver: null,
          _buttonFillPressed: null,
        }
      ),
      $(
        go.Panel,
        "Horizontal",
        { position: new go.Point(16, 0) },
        //// optional icon for each tree node
        //$(go.Picture,
        //  { width: 14, height: 14,
        //    margin: new go.Margin(0, 4, 0, 0),
        //    imageStretch: go.GraphObject.Uniform,
        //    source: "images/defaultIcon.png" },
        //  new go.Binding("source", "src")),
        $(go.TextBlock, new go.Binding("text", "key", (s) => "item " + s))
      ) // end Horizontal Panel
    ); // end Node

    // These are the links connecting tree nodes within each group.

    diagram.linkTemplate = $(go.Link); // without lines

    diagram.linkTemplate = // with lines
      $(
        go.Link,
        {
          selectable: false,
          routing: go.Link.Orthogonal,
          fromEndSegmentLength: 4,
          toEndSegmentLength: 4,
          fromSpot: new go.Spot(0.001, 1, 7, 0),
          toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
        },
        $(go.Shape, { stroke: "lightgray" })
      );

    // These are the blue links connecting a tree node on the left side with one on the right side.
    diagram.linkTemplateMap.add(
      "Mapping",
      $(
        MappingLink,
        {
          isTreeLink: false,
          isLayoutPositioned: false,
          layerName: "Foreground",
        },
        { fromSpot: go.Spot.Right, toSpot: go.Spot.Left },
        { relinkableFrom: true, relinkableTo: true },
        $(go.Shape, { stroke: "blue", strokeWidth: 2 })
      )
    );
    function updateNodeWidths(
      group: {
        memberParts: {
          each: (arg0: {
            (n: any): void;
            (n: any): void;
            (n: any): void;
          }) => void;
        };
      },
      width: number
    ) {
      if (isNaN(width)) {
        group.memberParts.each((n: { width: number }) => {
          if (n instanceof go.Node) n.width = NaN; // back to natural width
        });
      } else {
        var minx = Infinity; // figure out minimum group width
        group.memberParts.each((n: { actualBounds: { x: number } }) => {
          if (n instanceof go.Node) {
            minx = Math.min(minx, n.actualBounds.x);
          }
        });
        if (minx === Infinity) return;
        var right = minx + width;
        group.memberParts.each(
          (n: { width: number; actualBounds: { x: number } }) => {
            if (n instanceof go.Node)
              n.width = Math.max(0, right - n.actualBounds.x);
          }
        );
      }
    }
    function makeGroupLayout() {
      return $(
        go.TreeLayout, // taken from samples/treeView.html
        {
          alignment: go.TreeLayout.AlignmentStart,
          angle: 0,
          compaction: go.TreeLayout.CompactionNone,
          layerSpacing: 16,
          layerSpacingParentOverlap: 1,
          nodeIndentPastParent: 1.0,
          nodeSpacing: 0,
          setsPortSpot: false,
          setsChildPortSpot: false,
          // after the tree layout, change the width of each node so that all
          // of the nodes have widths such that the collection has a given width
          // commitNodes: function () {
          //   // overriding TreeLayout.commitNodes
          //   go.TreeLayout.prototype.commitNodes();
          //   if (ROUTINGSTYLE === "ToGroup") {
          //     updateNodeWidths(group, group.data.width || 100);
          //   }
          // },
        }
      );
    }
    diagram.groupTemplate = $(
      go.Group,
      "Auto",
      { deletable: false, layout: makeGroupLayout() },
      new go.Binding("position", "xy", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(
        go.Point.stringify
      ),
      new go.Binding("layout", "width", makeGroupLayout),
      $(go.Shape, { fill: "white", stroke: "lightgray" }),
      $(
        go.Panel,
        "Vertical",
        { defaultAlignment: go.Spot.Left },
        $(
          go.TextBlock,
          { font: "bold 14pt sans-serif", margin: new go.Margin(5, 5, 0, 5) },
          new go.Binding("text")
        ),
        $(go.Placeholder, { padding: 5 })
      )
    );

    // initialize tree on left side
    var root: any = { key: 0, group: -1 };
    nodeDataArray.push(root);
    for (var i = 0; i < 11; ) {
      i = makeTree(3, i, 17, nodeDataArray, linkDataArray, root, -1, root.key);
    }

    // initialize tree on right side
    root = { key: 1000, group: -2 };
    nodeDataArray.push(root);
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; ) {
      i = makeTree(3, i, 15, nodeDataArray, linkDataArray, root, -2, root.key);
    }
    diagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(nodeDataArray, linkDataArray);

    // help create a random tree structure
    function makeTree(
      level: number,
      count: number,
      max: number,
      nodeDataArray:
        | {
            isGroup: boolean;
            key: number;
            text: string;
            xy: string;
            width: number;
          }[]
        | { key: any; group: any }[],
      linkDataArray: { from: any; to: any }[],
      parentdata: { key: any; group?: any },
      groupkey: number,
      rootkey: number
    ) {
      var numchildren = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
      for (var i = 0; i < numchildren; i++) {
        if (count >= max) return count;
        count++;
        var childdata: any = { key: rootkey + count, group: groupkey };
        nodeDataArray.push(childdata);
        linkDataArray.push({ from: parentdata.key, to: childdata.key });
        if (level > 0 && Math.random() > 0.5) {
          count = makeTree(
            level - 1,
            count,
            max,
            nodeDataArray,
            linkDataArray,
            childdata,
            groupkey,
            rootkey
          );
        }
      }
      return count;
    }

    return diagram;
  }
  function handleModelChange(changes: any) {
    alert("GoJS model changed!");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactDiagram
        initDiagram={initDiagram}
        divClassName="diagram-component"
        nodeDataArray={nodeDataArray}
        linkDataArray={linkDataArray}
        onModelChange={handleModelChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) . See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Sorry for that, I just edited my question. I added my repo. You can find App.tsx file which has working code so far I can get.